# Migrating SQL DB from SQL 2005 to 2012 and going through Upgrade Advisor

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I needed to migrate a DB from SQL 2005 server ( residing in a 2003 Windows ) to SQL 2012 ( 2012 Windows ). Most of the threads recommends me to go through the Upgrade Advisor before migrating DB.

My concern is, as 2003 server almost outdated, I don't have one or in a situation can't provision new but I have 2008R2 and 2012 Windows servers. Can I perform the "Upgrade Advisor" exclusively via 2008/2012 server by restoring the DB in any of the above.

The current 2003 server is a live one so I am scared to perform the upgrade in it. So thinking of performing the "Upgrade Advisor" in a 3rd server to be on the safer side. Is that possible... Does Upgrade Advisor can perform the task from any server/edition to any server/edition.

In addition to that, does Upgrade Advisor is necessary or any other alternatives..

Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, Upgrade Advisor is required to know those things which would be necessary to be careful before migrating database from lower version to upper one. So, its better to be sure before migrating database. 
Next there are other third party tools that can perform similar plus some more extended features for migration of database. So you can search for those also, currently I will not prefer you any of them because that will cost you. 
Now, for migration of database from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012, its better to perform Upgrade Advisory from updated version. And if I am not wrong SQL Server provides such feature. So if needed I would prefer to preform Upgrade Advisor from Server 2012.